# Process dispatched jobs from queue automatically

Tags: laravel

I would like to process jobs from queue automatically.

I have this command:

`dispatch($importUserJob);`

Is it possible to run these jobs automatically or after few seconds?

Comment: Automatically, yes, just have a listener running: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker. I think you can pass a delay along with it too: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#delayed-dispatching

Comment: Thanks! Please add this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `Job` is `dispatch()`'ed, it is configured to be handled by the process configured in `config/queue.php`:

```
return [
  'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),
  'connections' => [
    'sync' => [...],
    'database' => [...],
    'beanstalkd' => [...],
    'sqs' => [...],
    'redis' => [...]
  ]
];
```

By default, this is set to `sync()`, and Jobs are automatically processed when run. In many production environments, this is set to `database`, and uses a `jobs` table (see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#driver-prerequisites Database section).

To process a `Job` dispatched to the Queue, you need a listener:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

This is a background process that automatically listens for `dispatch()`, and using the `jobs` table, processes the `Job` and it's `'payload'`. There are a variety of configuration options available, but they all function similarily.

Lastly, if you want to delay a `Job` processing, using the `->delay()` option:

```
dispatch(new ExampleJob(...))->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));
```

This will set the `jobs.available_at` column to the appropriate timestamp, and defer running until that time is reached.